# How to read a payload that is arriving in the body?

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

I am new to writing APIs. I am writing a post method that will receive JSon object as part of the body but I don't know how to read the body or possibly I'm not passing it properly in my test. I can see that the payload is there because the ContentLength matches exactly. The payload parameter is always null. This will be called from outside our company, so I have no control over how the payload is passed.

```
    [HttpPost("{site}/{customer}")]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]JObject payload)
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> body = null;

        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(mem, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            Request.Body.CopyToAsync(mem);
            body = reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }

        if (payload == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        string site = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["site"] != null ? this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["site"].ToString() : null;
        string customer = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["customer"] != null ? this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["customer"].ToString() : null;

        body.Dispose();

        return Ok();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IRestResponse response;

        JObject json;
        string temp = "{\"name\":\"Fred\"}";
        json = JObject.Parse(temp);

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");

        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://localhost:99999/api/Weather/XXX/1234");

        // Tried this
        request.AddJsonBody(json);

        // Tried this
        RequestBody body = new RequestBody("application/json", "payload", json);
        request.Body = body;

        // Tried this
        request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        response = client.Post(request);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just simply declare a type for the payload. It will be deserialized automately by the framework.

```
 public class MyPayload
 {
     [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("name")]
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }

 [HttpPost("{site}/{customer}")]
 public IActionResult Post([FromBody]MyPayload payload)
 {
     Debug.WriteLine(payload.Name); // Fred
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you not to use JObject as your API Parameter and declare a class to wrap it instead ([Donggas90's MyPayload class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63190332/) above looks great for you).

But, if you still want to do it that way, and pass just a lot of stuff without wrapping it, you can always receive an string in your API and deserialize it with JObject.

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string payload)
```

Call it without wrapping anything, just with the text you want to transform.

```
RequestBody myRequestbody = new RequestBody("application/json", "payload", "YourstringbodyBeforeJObjectParse");
```

And deserialize it in your API method with:

```
JObject.Parse(payload)
```

Anyway, creating a class that wraps all the content that the API can deserialize into is the BEST way to do it, even if its just for a string.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you donggas90 and Oscar for your help.  You were both right, using the class as the parameter type is the way to go.  That combined with changing the way my test method was setting/passing the payload did the trick.

```
RequestBody body = new RequestBody("application/json", "payload", json);
request.Body = body;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller we can use below code to read the request body payload

```
string requestBody = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
```